# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined angular

Tags: html, angular, laravel, jwt

I'm developing an app using Laravel as backend and Angular as frontend. To login and register I'm trying to use JWT but when I try to register using the register form I get the following error: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".

register.component.html

```
<form #registerForm=ngForm (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <div class="form-group row mx-auto">
      <label for="inputName3" class="col-md-6 col-form-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" 
          placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="form.name" required>
         <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2" [hidden]="!error.name">
            <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> {{error.name}}
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
...
</form>
```

register.component.js

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

   public form = {
       name: null,
       email: null,
       password: null,
       password_confirmation: null
   };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  onSubmit(){
    return this.http.post('http://localhost/api/auth/register', 
    this.form).subscribe(
      data => console.log(data),
      error => this.handleError(error)
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the template, your test `[hidden]='!error.name'` is not valid because the variable error is not defined in the controller (.ts).

Comment: I have the error defined like this `public error = [];`

Answer (score 0):

You should define error property with type object in the component.
because **Angular** expects an object called error with name key.

If you wait error from the backend or you need a quick solution just put `?` (question mark) after error word in HTML like: `[hidden]='!error?.name'`.

This will make **Angular** check for error variable before checking for name property.